# Symfony2 validator Length with min parameter allows empty value

Tags: validation, symfony

Today I found something strange about Symfony >=2.3 validators. I you use

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new Length(array('min' => 50)));
```

it allows empty inputs. I don't think it should do this or am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to make sure it's not blank then you should combine it with `NotBlank`. If it automatically validated an empty value as invalid then you would never be able to have a field that could be null OR the other validation without having to roll your own.

Comment: @Qoop, about null values you're right but for what then we validate minimum length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

Just think about the different use cases: a phone number can be optional, but if the user has entered a phone number, it should be at least 10 characters.

So you need to combine your Length constraint with a NotNull/NotBlank constraint.

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10221#issuecomment-34769066 for more explanation.

Btw : there is actually a brainstorming about empty string handling https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11956.