# Symfony Validation Constraint Assert\Date() is accepting empty string

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

In an Entity class I defined a property like

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class MyEntity
{
    ...

    /**
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    protected $date_of_birth;

    ...
}
```

In the FormType class I use the property:

```
$builder
    ->add('date_of_birth',
        DateType::class,
        array(
            'label' => 'Birthday',
            'required' => true,
            'translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'data' => null,
            'format' => $this->container->getParameter('date.format.icu'),
            'attr' => array( 'class' => 'js-bootstrap-datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'DD.MM.YYYY' ),
        )
    )
;
```

In the template I output the form suppressing browser side validation:

```
...
{{ form_start(form_a, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
...
{{ form_label(form_a.date_of_birth) }}*
{{ form_errors(form_a.date_of_birth) }}
{{ form_widget(form_a.date_of_birth) }}
...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't really matter what I type into the date field. I can leave it empty - it still is OK for the validator.
The NotBlank Constraint works though.
I suppose I am missing something specific in the Date Constraint usage?

Comment: You can have more than one constraint per field - add a new line to the annotation - `* @Assert\NotBlank()`

Comment: @AlisterBulman Thanks. This helps. Janney Botis answered it a bit more complete below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.
You are not missing anything, there is **no option** in the definition of the Date constraint to invalidate for empty value in the field.

To invalidate for empty value in the field, you should add the **NotBlank Constraint**, as you correctly state.

Here is the line: [code for DateValidator](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/3.3/Constraints/DateValidator.php#L50)

For example this is the same for most other validators, eg. [LengthValidator](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/3.3/Constraints/LengthValidator.php#L32) will validate for empty string, even if min is >0.

References:

1. [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25388191/4448410)
2. [Github issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11956)
3. [Explanation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10221#issuecomment-34769066)

Comment: Thank you. Got it :-) Small question aside: Is there a way to define a translation_domain for the message which I can define for an Assert?

Comment: Good question, unfortunately I do not know how.